# how to make different dev and prod route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to make different route between dev env and prod env..

for dev, I expect to use http://localhost:5000
but for prod I expect to use http://example.com/mdc

I tried below in startup

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                       name: "login_dev",
                       template: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}",
                       defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" });
            }
            else
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "login_prod",
                 template: "mdc/{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" });
            }

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{api}/{controller}/{action}");
        });
```

I got:

```
Application startup exception
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteCreationException: An error occurred while creating the route with name 'login_prod' and template 'mdc/{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The route parameter 'controller' has both an inline default value and an explicit default value specified. A route parameter cannot contain an inline default value when a default value is specified explicitly
```

Comment: error message clearly say it `A route parameter cannot contain an inline default value when a default value is specified explicitly` so just remove one of them

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46799555/6299857

Comment: `{controller=Account}/{action=Login}` should be `Account/Login`

Comment: Why do you want them different between dev and prod? Your routes shouldn't change. Just the base of the URL.

Comment: because in my prod, I install it on /var/www/html/mdc

Answer (score 2):

You can't have `inline default` and `explicit default` at the same time. so just change your routes to one of there options like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "login_prod",
                 template: "mdc/{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
```

**Or**

```
routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "login_prod",
                 template: "mdc/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" });
```

Comment: I tried that but it returns "Page not found" in production.. what I missed?

Comment: do I need to define all controllers one by one?
[CODE]
routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "test1_prod",
                 template: "mdc/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Test1", action = "Index" });

routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "test2_prod",
                 template: "mdc/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Test2", action = "Index" });

Comment: no this might because of mdc prefix you have. look more in Area in MVC pattern